# how to extract city and state from API for Indian PIN Code

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to extract city and state from Json array from Api for Indian Postal PIN code

```
var pincode = 400709;
    url='https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/'+ pincode;
    fetch(url) 
      .then(response => response.text())  
    .then(html => {             
var tpara = html.split(',');

console.log(tpara);
```

I get :-
Output

```
Array(14) [ '[{"Message":"Number of pincode(s) found:1"', '"Status":"Success"', '"PostOffice":[{"Name":"Kopar Khairne"', '"Description":null', '"BranchType":"Sub Post Office"', '"DeliveryStatus":"Delivery"', '"Circle":"Maharashtra"', '"District":"Thane"', '"Division":"New Mumbai"', '"Region":"Mumbai"', … ]
​
0: '[{"Message":"Number of pincode(s) found:1"'
​
1: '"Status":"Success"'
​
2: '"PostOffice":[{"Name":"Kopar Khairne"'
​
3: '"Description":null'
​
4: '"BranchType":"Sub Post Office"'
​
5: '"DeliveryStatus":"Delivery"'
​
6: '"Circle":"Maharashtra"'
​
7: '"District":"Thane"'
​
8: '"Division":"New Mumbai"'
​
9: '"Region":"Mumbai"'
​
10: '"Block":"NA"'
​
11: '"State":"Maharashtra"'
​
12: '"Country":"India"'
​
13: '"Pincode":"400709"}]}]'
​
length: 14
```

I Expect only (11) Maharashtra and (7) thane to be split out of this result and use as php variable

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works for me

```
var pincode = 441111;
    url='https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/'+ pincode;
    fetch(url) 
    .then(response => response.text())  
    .then(html => {
    var tpara = html.split(/,|\:/);
    console.log(tpara); 
   })
```

and I get all elements seperated